# Issue with installation of EMGU

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

The current docs [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Creating_a_New_Project_in_Visual_Studio) says:

> Creating a New Project in Visual Studio
> To use the framework in Visual Studio, you need to
>
> Download and extract the binary files package Emgu.CV.Windows.Binary-{version}.zip
> For a Full guide to using the dependencies under Visual Studio and C# see the C# Tutorial.

There is no link. I cannot find a download location for Emgu.CV.Windows.Binary-{version}.zip in my case it would be emgu.cv.windows.binary-4.3.0.3890.zip. I can't find this file anywhere including my hard drive after installing.

Are the installation instruction wrong? Are these found in one of the EMGU nuget packages? If so, which one?

Also, I am a bit confused with the various flavors or C# OpenCV wrappers and all the various  installation instruction out there.

Help getting OpenCV C# wrapper running would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah yes... the joy of Emgu.CV documentation.

Be sure to include the **two** NuGet packages below. The later includes the required binaries:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to contribute to the documentation or is the system so broken it's a big uphill battle?

Comment: I don't believe there is any community maintenance of the documentation, although there is a forum and bug reporting.  The main trouble is that the official tutorials and examples have not been maintained for a long time. I might post some basic FAQs on here when I find the time. Otherwise I watch this tag so can try to help with most issues. There's some other active guy who are very good also.

Comment: Did these NuGets get you up and running at least?

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try yet. Hopefully Monday.

Comment: @EricSnyder So? All okay?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Haven't been able to test. Am working in another "hot" area.

Comment: @EricSnyder Great!