# EMGU CV with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, computer-vision, emgucv

I would like to use EMGU in vb.net. I have tried to follow several youtube videos with no joy. I have downloaded v 4.3 and also tried to use Nuget manager in visual studio but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any experience of getting this working from the ground up?

Comment: What is the problem with Nuget Manager?

Comment: I have installed it via nuget but can’t get any of the examples I can find to work. I just want to be able to use it to detect a cap lid on a bottle (I have the images as jpg)

Comment: Did you `Imports Emgu.CV` and
`Imports Emgu.Util` at the top of the code file?

Comment: Yes, everything I read and watch says this is easy in C# but can’t make it work in VB. my existing huge project is in Vb

Comment: Do you have working code in C#? There are several converters available on the internet.

Comment: No, nothing I can find seems to work!!!

Comment: Check my answer here perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698324/issue-with-installation-of-emgu. Most likely you're missing the runtime .dlls